# Getting this error Firebase Error (auth/invalid-api-key)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, next.js

Im getting the error 'Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key) ' even though all my authentication values were correct.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you show how the authentication code is laid out. This question is not descriptive. In any case, @yoster-daniel 's answer is what you're missing perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a separate file called 'firebase.config.js'. In the file, only have an 'export const' variable with the credentials for the firebase. Here is my file:

```
export const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_ID,
    measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MEAUREMENT_ID 
  
  };
```

2. Go back to 'firebase.js' file, remove credentials from there, then reference the recently created variable from file with this line

```
import { firebaseConfig } from './firebase.config';
```

3. Finally, Initialize the Firebase shown below

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth();
export const db = getFirestore(app);
```